# Me da este error The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties

Tags: c#

```
public HtmlButton UILoginButton
        {
            get
            {
                if ((this.mUILoginButton == null))
                {
                    this.mUILoginButton = new HtmlButton(this);
                    #region Search Criteria
                   this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
                   this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
                    this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.DisplayText] = "Login";
                    this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Type] = "button";
                  this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
                    this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Class] = "btn btn-primary px-4";
                    this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "class=\"btn btn-primary px-4\" type=\"button;
                    this.mUILoginButton.SearchProperties[HtmlButton.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "1";
                    this.mUILoginButton.WindowTitles.Add("http://localhost:81/etesplus/#/security/login");
                    #endregion
                }
                return this.mUILoginButton;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. El error te especifica que no es capaz de encontrar el control con las propiedades de búsqueda que indicas. Deberías al menos poner la definición del boton para que podamos revisarla.

Comment: Por cierto, puedes revisar [esto](https://gist.github.com/abul4fia/b9a02ac828091125bf8062dd0203a55d)  para aprender a formatear el código.